# How to query for members of an LDAP group using Powershell not in MS Active Directory

Tags: powershell, directory, ldap

All I am trying to accomplish is to return if an LDAP group has any members in it. So, I have a list of groups, and I want to query each one for a list of members to ensure there is at least 1 member in every group.

I am using powershell and this is NOT Active Directory.

This is currently what I am trying

```
$user = "username"
$pwd = "password"
$de = "LDAP://[SERVERNAME]/cn=user,ou=people,o=company"
$deObject = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($de,$user,$pwd,'FastBind')
```

This returns a DirectoryEntry object (at least as far as I can tell). I can't really see any attributes or anything except for if I do the following:

```
$deObject.Name
```

This returns the cn of "user" and that's it. Any suggestions?

I've tried:

```
$deObject.Properties
$deObject.Properties['member']
$deObject.Properties.Values['member']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: some hints: http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/29100-bind-ldap-directory.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show you all the properties there are:

```
$deObject | Format-List * -force
```

And this will return you the number of members in a group:

```
$deObject.member.Count
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am actually able to get the list of members and the full cn using: `$deObject.member` and `$deObject.Name`

The odd thing though, is that the `$deObject | Format-List * -Force` throws an "Unknown error (0x8000500c)"